# I am seen by millions

Tags: riddle

This is my first attempt at a riddle:

I am seen by millions
But remembered by few
Some fear my arrival
Most look forward to me
At times I can be controlled
But usually do my own thing
People sometimes look to me for answers
Though I have no voice to speak to them

What am I?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the answer could be

> dreams / a dream

I am seen by millions

> pretty much everyone dreams

But remembered by few

> but not as many people remember them, at least not in detail

Some fear my arrival

> dreams can be terrifying, and recurring nightmares aren't uncommon

Most look forward to me

> but a good dream lets you live out your fantasies

At time I can be controlled

> lucid dreaming is dreaming when you are aware that you are dreaming and can control the dream

But usually do my own thing

> but this isn't something everyone experiences and can be difficult to learn

People sometimes look to me for answers

> people interpret dreams to try and find answers about their worries, their future, their destiny, etc.

Though I have no voice to speak to them

> This is the one I am least certain about, but I suppose you can't interrogate your dream to ask it what means.

Comment: We have a winner!

Answer (score 5):

Possibly wrong but is it

> The wind?

I am seen by millions

> Well not actually the wind but its effect on trees, etc.

But remembered by few

> You don't want to remember all the times you've seen the wind blow

Some fear my arrival

> Nobody likes hurricane winds

Most look forward to me

> If it's hot a breeze is welcome

At time I can be controlled

> People plant trees, put barriers etc to stop the wind

But usually do my own thing

> It sure does its own thing

People sometimes look to me for answers

> "The answer my friend is blowin' in the wind"

Though I have no voice to speak to them

> No, it has no actual voice.

Comment: That mostly works, but that's not the answer I'm looking for.
The remembered by few is involuntary.

Answer (score 4):

Another answer could be:

> Stars

I am seen by millions

> Looking at the sky at night

But remembered by few

> Few remember stars

Some fear my arrival

> Omen in the stars

Most look forward to me

> Stars can be beautiful

At time I can be controlled

> Telescopes choose the stars you see

But usually do my own thing

> Stars are born, die and move constantly

People sometimes look to me for answers

> Reading the stars

Though I have no voice to speak to them

> Stars can't speak

Comment: I'll give that a +1, it mostly works.  Though using a telescope to choose the stars you see doesn't actually control the stars themselves so that line doesn't quite work.

Comment: @AndrewF yeah that's the one that doesn't quite fit

Answer (score 3):

I know this is incorrect, but fits quite well

> The Silence from Doctor Who

---

I am seen by millions

> Millions of people have seen them

But remembered by few

> Once you lose eye contact, you will forget about them

Some fear my arrival

> They are pretty scary!

Most look forward to me

> The Docto Who fans that is, it's one of the most popular races.

At time I can be controlled

> Didn't they control them in one or two episodes?

But usually do my own thing

> They are sentient beings

People sometimes look to me for answers

> The Silence will fall when Question is asked.

Though I have no voice to speak to them

> They do not speak.

Comment: But they do speak, remember the scene where Amy was in the bathroom and she asked one of the Silence why they killed that other woman?

Comment: Wasn't that telepathy? To be fair I know some of these clues don't match 100% but I still thought it would be funny to mention how many of them do match.

Answer (score 1):

Another controversial one may go to...

> GMOs

---

I am seen by millions

> Of course, you may say billions

But remembered by few

> Hunch is sometimes utilised by many.

Some fear my arrival

> "Some" is another controversial one also.

Most look forward to me

> Previous mentioned group are not included.

At time I can be controlled

> Well, yeah. Kind of.

But usually do my own thing

> Business is business, right?

People sometimes look to me for answers

> It is controversial, people.

Though I have no voice to speak to them

> But my owners do anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This works decently:

> Billboards

I am seen by millions

> Millions of people daily see the billboards lining the roads and on the sides of buildings.

But remembered by few

> Billboards tend to pass out of one's memory pretty quickly

Some fear my arrival

> Some billboards contain cataclysmic messages

Most look forward to me

> Many billboards are posted on the sides of roads facing oncoming traffic so that people seated in the forward position will see them.

At times I can be controlled

> Some electronic billboards allow custom messaging

But usually do my own thing

> ...but usually they are fixed.

People sometimes look to me for answers

> Billboards can contain useful information on business locations, religious guidance, traffic conditions, etc.

Though I have no voice to speak to them

> Typically they do not make sound.